# Spring DATA JPA @ManyToOne : foreign key is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, relational-database

When I'm going to Save an order Perfectly Saving but the Order Table Foreign key is always null!

I am using the Mysql database.

Here are my entity relations:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int orderID;
    private double total;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID", referencedColumnName = "username")
    private User userID;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OrderDetails> orderDetails;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "systemuser")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleCode", referencedColumnName = "UserRoleCode")
    private UserRole roleCode;

    private String address;
    @Id
    private String username;
    private String status;
    private String phoneNo1;
    private String phoneNo2;
    private String idPhoto;
    private String remarks;
    private String email;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userID", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Order> orders;

}
```

All Primary keys Are AutoGenerated.If You have any other method to achieve this task

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just need to add `foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)`to your `@JoinColumn`

Comment: its not work for me